# Search and detect overlap in a list of Objects by start and end timestamps

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, collections

I've got a List and I want to detect overlapped Mission's in the list by device String attribute. So, Mission will be like:

```
public class Mission {
    private String id;
    private String device;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
}
```

I receive a List and want to return the same list with the subtask attribute set to "overlap" if:

- There is another mission by the same device during its range (timestampstart to timestampend).

Recall that I need to mark ALL the overlapped missions. When I find them in the list, mark the current one (if matches) and the encountered in the list.

I want to do it with the LESS possible cost. Non expensive operations.

Comment: Why do you use `List<Object>` instead of `List<Mission>`? Are two `Mission`s equal when their `id` is equal? Are the lists ordered by e.g. the `id`? If the answer to the last two questions is "yes", then you can achieve what you want in `n * log(m)`.

Comment: @Turing85 I use List<Mission>. Their id's are never equal. I can sort it by timestamp (start for example). The thing is how to implement it in Java properly.

Comment: Most probably, you have to overwrite [`equals(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) (mind that there is a contract between `equals(...)` and [`hashCode(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())).

Comment: Now we know what you want. We don't know what **YOU** have tried or researched so far. What is your concrete problem? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I you have a possibility to use additional memory, I can offer you the following alghorithm

1. Create `HashMap<String, TreeSet<Mission>> map` where `device` is a key.
2. TreeSet have to be sorted by `startTime`. Example `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Mission::getStartTime))`
3. Initialize `map` with data from your list. Main idea here to group your data by `device` and order grouped data by `startTime`.
4. Then iterate over your list and apply the following alghorithm:

   1. Find TreeSet in created map: `TreeSet<Mission> set = map.get(item.device)`. If it's size is equal to 1 then you can move to the next item in your list because this only item of set have the same id that original item from list.
   2. Find subset from set received in step 1 with elements, which `startTime` lower that `item.endTime`. If it's size is equal to 1 then you can move to the next item in your list because this only item of subset have the same id that original item from list. Code example: `set = set.headSet(new Mission().setStartTime(item.getEndTime()))`
   3. Find first element in subset from step 2, which `endTime` more than original `item.startTime`. I would recommend you to move over subset in backward order `set.descendingIterator()` If you found one and it's id is not equal to original item id then you can mark item as overlapped and move to the next item of your list. Otherwise repeat step 3 for the next element of subset till the end.

Comment: This works well. However, when you can mark the current item that you are iterating on the list in step 3, but you are not marking the item that matches (the found one with different id).

Comment: I just filled a Set<String> with the id's from the detected missions, and then iterate again over the list to set the Missions as overlapped.

Comment: As I understood from question description overlap happens when two missions have equal device and they time intervals (time between start and end) overlaps. Algorithm looks so complicated because it follows the last condition. If there is no need to control time intervals, you can replace `HashMap<String, TreeSet<Mission>>` to `HashMap<String, Integer>`, where value is a count of device ids. And if count > 1 then mark `Mission` with overlap